# How to insert some calculating in middle level loop?

Tags: halide

i am a new guy tring Halide programming. I met an issue when porting some halide code into android via Halide::Generator. Below is my code:

```
#include "Halide.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace Halide;
using namespace Halide::ConciseCasts;
using namespace std;


class TestGenerator : public Halide::Generator<TestGenerator> 
{ 
public:
    Input<Buffer<uint16_t>> imgs{"imgs", 3};

    void generate() 
    {   
        Func imgs_mirror = BoundaryConditions::mirror_interior(imgs, 0, imgs.width(), 0, imgs.height());
        Func F1("F1");

        RDom r0(0, 16, 0, 16);       
        Var ix, iy, tx_m, ty_m, n_m; 
        Buffer<uint16_t> ref_val(16, 16), alt_val(16, 16);
        ref_val(r0.x, r0.y) = imgs_mirror(tx_m*16+r0.x, ty_m*16+r0.y, 0);
        alt_val(r0.x, r0.y) = imgs_mirror(al_x, al_y, 1);

        ... //process

        Var ix2, iy2;
        RDom r2(0, 16, 0, 16); 

        F1(ix2, iy2, tx_m, ty_m) = ref_val(r2.x, r2.y);

        F1.compute_root();
    }
};

HALIDE_REGISTER_GENERATOR(TestGenerator, test_generator)
```

The expected process is that:
1. tx_m and ty_m handle top level(outer) loop
2. ix and iy handle bottom level(inner) loop(which are fixed as block of 16x16)
3. use a Buffer:ref_val and alt_val of 16x16 to accept iterating result for ix and iy, then do some calculating, fill the result into ref_val
4. feed ref_val back into the same position(ix2, iy2, tx_m, ty_m) of a Func.

When i compile and run it, i got below error:
In pure definition of Func "F1":
Reduction domain referenced in pure function definition.
Aborted (core dumped)

I also tried below:
    F1(ix2, iy2, tx_m, ty_m) = ref_val(ix2, iy2);
The compiling and run is Ok, and the static library is generated successfully, but when i run it in android, it will crash with below overflow issue:
I halide  : Error: Input buffer ref_val_bf is accessed at 31, which is beyond the max (15) in dimension 0

Could anyone give me a hand?

Thanks very much!